# PostGIS query of point feature ~ Find nearest point to query location?

Tags: postgis, sql

I am querying a point feature using a PostGIS request fired in JavaScript.  The decoded URL looks like this and returns great results for polygon features.

```
http://test.tablelocation.com/api/v1/sql/?q=select '+tempCoi+' from '+tempTableName+' where ST_Intersects(the_geom, ST_GeomFromText('POINT('+clickLng+' '+clickLat+')',4326))&format=json&diagnostics=true&_maxage=86400&callback=?
```

As you can see, there are a few dynamic Javascript variables that are injected into each URL request.  Two of these variables (clickLng and clickLat) specify the lat/lng of my query.  They are generated based on where the user clicks on a google map.  I am returning one attribute from the point layer referenced via the tempCoi variable.  When I try to query a point feature, no data is returned.

I am guessing that this is because the location of my query is too specific (i.e. 6+ decimal points).

To make a long question shorter, is there a way to fuzz my data request.

For example, if I click at 45.123456N and -113.654987W how could I look for the closest point to that query?

Hope this is clear...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing SQL in your URLs directly looks risky to me.

Otherwise, the method you are looking for is
https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html

Comment: Thanks Relet..  I'll look into ST_DWithin.  Why is passing URLs risky?  I am pretty new to web development.

Comment: Passing SQL code is risky. What happens if someone calls that URL with q=drop+database+yourdatabasename ? You may have set the correct permissions to disallow that, but in general database permissions are not fine grained enough to prevent all forms of possible abuse (for a less drastic example, reading data from tables that shouldn't be public).